# iOS UITableViewController even a little scroll at top shows UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am facing an unexpected problem with my tableview for UITableViewController. Testing in iOS 9.2

I have enabled "refreshing" for the UITableViewController in storyboard and attached it's IBAction for valueChanged. Note that the tableview has section headers using the "Plain" style and custom height of 45.

The problem is that usually you will expect to pull down the tableview considerable amount for it to trigger the refresh control and start spinning.

However in my scenario however, even a tiny bit of scroll makes the refresh control to show up and start spinning. Like literally 2 centimeters and that will make it appear. It's even weird that it automatically expands in height even though I haven't even pulled the tableview enough to trigger the refresh.

Also note that even though it starts spinning completely and automatically ends spinning too but my method linked in the IBAction for the refresh control doesn't actually get triggered yet.

For example I am scrolling up slowly and as soon as I am about to reach the top, the refresh control will show up and move the tableview down, start spinning, stop spinning. All this without pulling the tableview considerable amount.

Note that in my code, I don't have "beginRefreshing" anywhere at all. Also I don't have any "scrollViewDidScroll" or "scrollViewDidDrag" etc methods to trigger the refresh control.

I have never seen this sort of issue at all. I can't use a custom ViewController with custom TableView due to other reasons, so need to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by deleting the app and reinstalling it after cleaning and rebuilding. Very weird problem which I spent lot of time but now it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `UIRefreshControl` programmatically, and it will work correctly. Here is a simple example, where UIRefreshControl is not a `IBOutlet` (I didn't include tableView datasource methods):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    self.refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(actionRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
}

- (void)actionRefresh:(id)sender {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}

// ...UITableView dataSource methods

@end
```

Comment: i actually had it this way before and had the same issue. So I decided to switch to the storyboard enable "refreshing" and removed the code and still same issue :(

Comment: Here is a test project where just the same code as in answer, and it works fine. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jka44ujmintnh5x/AABDtzyW3GO0Al9PuoNtrFlea?dl=0

Comment: I am not doubting that your code doesn't work. I have other tableviewccontrollers where this works correctly. Only this one is where it doesn't

Comment: thanks for you help! I was able to resolve it by deleting the app and reinstalling it after cleaning and rebuilding. Very weird problem which I spent lot of time but now it's fixed!